# How to see if an element is contained inside a list

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following list

```
catlist <- list(c("< 30 days","1-3 months","4-6 months"),c("7-12 months"),c("1-3 years"),
                  c("4-5 years","5+ years","never"))
```

Which i give names

```
names(catlist) <- 1:length(catlist)
```

More over I have a `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- data.table(variable = c("never","1-3 years"))
```

What I would like to do, is to create a new variable (`new_variable`) in the `tmp`, which will have as value the name of the `catlist` in which the value
of the `variable` falls into

So in the end I would like to end up with this

```
> tmp
    variable new_variable
1:     never            4
2: 1-3 years            3
```

I tried to create a function but it doesn't work

```
trans_dummy_multiple <- function(dt, var, catlist){

  dt <- tmp # for testing
  var <- "variable" # for testing
  catlist <- list(c("< 30 days","1-3 months","4-6 months"),c("7-12 months"),c("1-3 years"),
                  c("4-5 years","5+ years","never")) # for testing
  names(catlist) <- 1:length(catlist)
  dt[,new_variable:=lapply(catlist,function(x){if(x%in%get(var)){names(x)}})]


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
scl<-setDT(stack(catlist))
scl[tmp,on=c(values="variable")]
#      values ind
#1:     never   4
#2: 1-3 years   3
```

Comment: i get an error when i use `stack`: `...< 30 days' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.`

Comment: You got some loaded package we are not aware of. Use `utils::stack` and check the packages you are using.

Comment: Translated to "create a new variable in tmp" there's `tmp[, new_variable := scl[tmp,on=c(values="variable"), ind]]` I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a solution using `grep`:

```
tmp <- data.frame(variable = c("never","1-3 years"), stringsAsFactors = F)
df <- transform(tmp, new_variable = sapply(df$variable, function(item) grep(item, catlist)))
df
```

This yields

```
   variable new_variable
1     never            4
2 1-3 years            3
```

Comment: do you think there is a way to avoid the for loop ?

Comment: so the `col` is the name of the (existing) variable in the `data.table` right ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `melt`

```
setDT(melt(catlist))[tmp, on = .(value = variable)]
#       value L1
#1      never  4
#2: 1-3 years  3
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using the `utils::stack()` function (got the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799296/convert-list-to-dataframe-in-r-and-add-column-with-names-of-sub-lists)) and `dplyr` (I don't have experience with `data.table`). Add this to your code:

```
require(dplyr)

catlist2 <- catlist %>%
  stack()

tmp <- tmp %>%
  left_join(y = catlist2, by = c("variable" = "values"))

#   variable ind
# 1     never   4
# 2 1-3 years   3
```